# UK visa upload process: forgot to upload support letter

Tags: visas, uk

I forgot to upload the main document of my UK visa application (support letter) and have submitted all uploaded document via TLS service. Is there any way to add the document (e.g. pay onsite in the application center or cancel the application and start again), because without that I cannot get the visa?

Answer (score 2):

I found a temporary solution. I canceled my self-service appointment and paid for the assisted service.